# How to aggregate based on one repeated value in a column

Tags: sql, oracle, aggregate

I'm trying to aggregate data based on one particular field in my PL/SQL procedure. I have this table, let's call it MYTABLE:

[image]

And I want to obtain the following:

[image: DESIRED RESULT]

Values of column c have to appear only once,
values of column d have to be the same as the d value of the lines having b=1 and c=1111,
values of column e have to be populated with the minimum value of column e for the two equal line in c (min between 0 and -1 of 1111)

Thanks,
Ilaria

Comment: not at all getting what you are trying to do

Comment: Let's start saying that I don't have to have duplicated values in column c

Comment: Please read http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/285551/why-may-i-not-upload-images-of-code-on-so-when-asking-a-question/285557 and the accepted answer

Comment: Ilaria I added some examples of how to control different aggregations with KEEP, FIRST, LAST.  Do these make sense?  If not just let me know we can start a new question that goes into that more.  Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

PL/SQL is not required for this.  You can do your aggregation in SQL.

After setting up the data:

```
CREATE TABLE MYTABLE (
  A NUMBER,
  B NUMBER,
  C NUMBER,
  D NUMBER,
  E NUMBER
);

INSERT INTO MYTABLE VALUES (111, 0, 1111, 11, 0);
INSERT INTO MYTABLE VALUES (222, 1, 2222, 22, 1);
INSERT INTO MYTABLE VALUES (222, 1, 1111, 22, 1);
INSERT INTO MYTABLE VALUES (222, 1, 3333, 22, 1);
COMMIT;
```

We can first make our only goal selecting `DISTINCT` values of C, and do so by `GROUP BY` C:

```
SQL> SELECT C
  2  FROM MYTABLE
  3  GROUP BY C;

2222  
1111  
3333
```

Then, to get the lowest value of `E` for each distinct value of `C`, we must apply an aggregate function to E, so there is only one value returned for each unique value of `C`:

```
SQL> SELECT C, MIN(E) AS E
  2  FROM MYTABLE
  3  GROUP BY C
  4  ORDER BY C ASC, E ASC;

1111  0  
2222  1  
3333  1
```

**Please note this disagrees with the example table you provided, but should be in keeping with your described goal:**

> "values of column e have to be populated with the minimum value of
>   column e for the two equal line in c"

Then to include `D`, we will again need an aggregate function (This will be the case for each column besides `C`, since a unique value needs to be returned for each non-`C` column.  In this case the value is not a simple `MIN`/`MAX` but has some dependency on the value of `B` as well.  In this case I would suggest `KEEP` in your aggregate function.  The below will work for the sample you've provided, but you may need to alter the conditions to work with your goals:

```
SQL> SELECT C,
  2    MIN(D) KEEP (DENSE_RANK LAST ORDER BY B ASC) AS D,
  3    MIN(E) AS E
  4  FROM MYTABLE
  5  GROUP BY C
  6  ORDER BY C ASC, D ASC, E ASC;

1111  22  0  
2222  22  1  
3333  22  1
```

Compare the above with this alternative, and one can see the value of `B` is being considered:

```
SQL> SELECT C,
  2    MIN(D) KEEP (DENSE_RANK LAST ORDER BY B DESC) AS D,
  3    MIN(E) AS E
  4  FROM MYTABLE
  5  GROUP BY C
  6  ORDER BY C ASC, D ASC, E ASC;

1111  11  0  
2222  22  1  
3333  22  1
```

Then, to finish the query, apply aggregate functions to `A` and `B`.  You didn't specify how you wanted to compress them, so I'm just using `MIN` as a placeholder that happens to work with your data.

```
SQL> SELECT
  2    MIN(A) AS A,
  3    MIN(B) AS B,
  4    C      AS C,
  5    MIN(D) KEEP (DENSE_RANK LAST ORDER BY B ASC) AS D,
  6    MIN(E) AS E
  7  FROM MYTABLE
  8  GROUP BY C
  9  ORDER BY C ASC, A ASC, B ASC, D ASC, E ASC;

111  0  1111  22  0  
222  1  2222  22  1  
222  1  3333  22  1
```

**EDIT:** for further discussion about `FIRST`/`LAST`:

Here's an example to illustrate `KEEP` and ranking.
There's a lot to explore with these, the [documentation](https://docs.oracle.com/cd/B19306_01/server.102/b14200/functions056.htm) can be useful.

To explore what KEEP is doing, I'll switch to a general example with movies.  Suppose you had the following table.  It includes movie studios, movie titles they produce, along with their profit and how much people like them:

```
CREATE TABLE MOVIE(
  MOVIE_TITLE VARCHAR2(200) NOT NULL PRIMARY KEY,
  DISTRIBUTOR VARCHAR2(200) NOT NULL,
  MONEY_MADE  NUMBER(15,2) NOT NULL,
  REVIEW_SCORE NUMBER(3,0) NOT NULL
);
INSERT INTO MOVIE VALUES ('Avatar','Fox',2787965087,83);
INSERT INTO MOVIE VALUES ('Aliens','Fox',183000000,98);
--Not true moned-made, but just pretend
INSERT INTO MOVIE VALUES ('Prometheus','Fox',2787965087,72);
INSERT INTO MOVIE VALUES ('Terminator','Orion',78000000,100);
INSERT INTO MOVIE VALUES ('RoboCop','Orion',53000000,88);
COMMIT;
```

Both 'Fox' and 'Orion' in this example appear in the data multiple times.
If we want to, we can find the most profit on a single movie for each studio with standard aggregation:

```
SQL> SELECT DISTRIBUTOR, MAX(MONEY_MADE) FROM MOVIE
  2  GROUP BY DISTRIBUTOR;
DISTRIBUTOR  MAX(MONEY_MADE)  
Orion        78000000         
Fox          2787965087
```

But, that doesn't actually tell us which movie made the most money.  We could try to take MIN or MAX on the title, but that wouldn't help since the `MAX` movie maybe didn't make the most money; they are in different columns--they are independent.  So we instead can `KEEP` the movie that made the most money.  The "fact" that Prometheus and Avatar made the same amount of money matters here:

```
SELECT DISTRIBUTOR, 
  MAX(MOVIE_TITLE) KEEP (DENSE_RANK LAST ORDER BY MONEY_MADE ASC) AS MOVIE_TITLE
FROM MOVIE
GROUP BY DISTRIBUTOR;

DISTRIBUTOR  MOVIE_TITLE  
Fox          Prometheus   
Orion        Terminator
```

This says: *"For each Movie Studio, go get the movies that made the most money, and if there's a tie, just get the MAX (alphabetic) so I only have one row"*.
`DENSE_RANK` and `FIRST`/`LAST` is what gets us the highest-earning movie(s) per studio.  `KEEP` comes in and says "*RANK the movies per studio by their MONEY_MADE, and only KEEP the LAST (most profitable) one(s)*".  Since we have a tie between Avatar and Prometheus, the `KEEP` will return those two, then `MAX` helps resolve the tie (alphabetically).

If I switch to `MIN`, I'll get Avatar because it is alphabetically first:

```
SELECT DISTRIBUTOR,
  MIN(MOVIE_TITLE) KEEP (DENSE_RANK LAST ORDER BY MONEY_MADE ASC) AS MOVIE_TITLE
FROM MOVIE
GROUP BY DISTRIBUTOR;
DISTRIBUTOR  MOVIE_TITLE  
Fox          Avatar       
Orion        Terminator
```

If I `KEEP` the `FIRST` instead of the `LAST`, I'll get the lowest-money-made per studio:

```
SELECT DISTRIBUTOR,
  MIN(MOVIE_TITLE) KEEP (DENSE_RANK FIRST ORDER BY MONEY_MADE ASC) AS MOVIE_TITLE
FROM MOVIE
GROUP BY DISTRIBUTOR;
DISTRIBUTOR  MOVIE_TITLE  
Fox          Aliens       
Orion        RoboCop
```

In this way, `KEEP` and `RANK` let us compare across rows and have more control what the aggregation returns.

I hope this helps.

Comment: Thanks alex!!! This is pretty what I was looking for! But I can't understand very well line MIN(D) KEEP (DENSE_RANK LAST ORDER BY B ASC) AS D. What do KEEP and DENSE_RANK do together? Thanks a lot!

Comment: Thanks Illaria.  I'll update my answer above with a little discussion about FIRST and LAST and analytics, but as that will take us away from the original question somewhat, I'll try to be brief.  Then If you'd like, you can close this question and ask about that.  I'll follow up in just a few